# difference between two proportion in SPSS

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, proportion

The following is a toy example to help me understand how to perform test of difference between two proportions in SPSS.

I have two main geographic regions (Region 1 and Region 2)  and several subregions (Subregion A, Subregion B, Subregion C and Subregion D) on which I recorded answers to simple questions.

For instance, 'Do you prefer ice-cream or coffee after lunch?'

The sample size is 700 for both regions.

I obtained the following table of results, so that in Region 1, 209 people out of 700 prefer ice-cream rather than coffee:

[image]

How can I know if the difference in the two proportions is statistically significant?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+of+proportions gives you many good answers.  But the difference in your data is so stark and so obvious that you don't need a test.  As far as using SPSS goes, please find an SPSS manual or discussion list -- that detail is not on topic here.